# Admin login using custom midlewares RedirectIfAdmin, RedirectIfNotAdmin but getting error **localhost redirected you too many times**

Tags: authentication, laravel-6.2

**RedirectIfAdmin** mdilleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = 'admin')
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::ADMIN_HOME);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

**RedirectIfNotAdmin** middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = 'admin')
{
    if (!Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('admin/login');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

**AdminHomeController** construct function

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('admin');
}
```

**Kernel.php**

```
'admin'         => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfNotAdmin::class,
'admin.guest'   => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAdmin::class,
```

In **RouteServiceProvider** I have made customised **mapAdminRoute**

```
protected function mapAdminRoutes()
{
    Route::prefix('admin/')
         ->as('admin.')
         ->middleware(['web','admin'])
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/admin.php'));
}
```

But after login I am getting redirect to many time on login dashboard login dashboard.
 I was getting error **app/Http/Middleware/CheckIfAdmin**: No such directory then I installed **backpack\crud** but still the problem is as it is. My **admin** middleware is not working as I have also checked by writing dd() in **RedirectIfNotAdmin** middleware instead of dd() it is redirecting again and again on login and dashboard respectively and continuously.